# How to Get hierarchical nested object of mongoose data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, categories

I have data like this:

```
[{ "id": 80, "Category": "1", "sub_category": null},
 { "id": 81, "Category": "1.1", "sub_category": 80},
{ "id": 82, "Category": "1.1.1", "sub_category": 81},
{ "id": 83, "Category": "1.2", "sub_category": 80},
{ "id": 84, "Category": "1.1.1.1", "sub_category": 82}]
```

i am using express js with mongoose. node version 10.19.0 and npm version 6.14.9 and express js version 4.17.1.
i have a category table and i have to get data with hierarchical nested data.
like this

```
 { "id": 80, 
   "Category": "1", 
   "sub_category": null, 
   "SubCategories": [{ "id": 81, 
                       "Category": "1.1", 
                       "sub_category": 80,
                       "SubCategories": [{ "id": 82, 
                                            "Category": "1.1.1", 
                                            "sub_category": 81,
                                            "SubCategories": [{ "id": 84, 
                                                                "Category": "1.1.1.1", 
                                                                "sub_category": 82,
                                                                "SubCategories": [...]
                                                              },]
                                           },]
                     },
                     { "id": 83, 
                       "Category": "1.2", 
                       "sub_category": 80,
                       "SubCategories": [...]
                     },]
 }
```

I tried graphLookup query for that,

```
CategoryModel.aggregate([{
  $graphLookup: {
    from: "examcategories", 
    startWith: "$id", 
    connectFromField: "id", 
    connectToField: "sub_category", 
    as: "SubCategoies" 
  } 
}])
```

and get output like this

```
{ 
  "id": 80, 
  "Category": "1", 
  "sub_category": null,
  "SubCategories": [{ 
    "id": 81,
    "Category": "1.1",
    "sub_category": 80 
   },{ 
     "id": 82,
     "Category":"1.1.1",
     "sub_category": 81 
   },{ 
     "id": 84,
     "Category": "1.1.1.1",
     "sub_category": 82 
   },{ 
     "id": 83,
     "Category": "1.2",
     "sub_category": 80,
   }
]}
```

Comment: Try using $graphLookup aggregation

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) performs a recursive search on a collection, with options for restricting the search by recursion depth and query filter, but just `$groupLookup` not enough for this, need to use more operators

- `$match` filter that records only have `sub_category` is `null`
- `$graphLookup` to get sub category records and depth number in defthField `level`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `SubCategories` array and allow to not remove empty sub categories
- `$sort` by depth level field `level` in descending order
- `$group` by `id` field and reconstruct `SubCategories` array

```
CategoryModel.aggregate([
  { $match: { sub_category: null } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "examcategories",
      startWith: "$id",
      connectFromField: "id",
      connectToField: "sub_category",
      depthField: "level",
      as: "SubCategories"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$SubCategories",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "SubCategories.level": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      sub_category: { $first: "$sub_category" },
      Category: { $first: "$Category" },
      SubCategories: { $push: "$SubCategories" }
    }
  },
```

- `$addFields` now find the nested level sub categories and allocate to its level,

  - `$reduce` to iterate loop of `SubCategories` array.
  - initialize default field `level` default value is -1, `presentChild` is [], `prevChild` is [] for the conditions purpose
  - `$let` to initialize fields:

    - `prev` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `prevChild` otherwise return `presentChild`
    - `current` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `presentChild` otherwise []
  - `in` to return `level` field and `prevChild` field from initialized fields

    - `presentChild` `$filter` `SubCategories` from `prev` array and return, merge current objects with `SubCategories` array using `$mergeObjects` and concat with `current` array of let using `$concatArrays`
- `$addFields` to return only `presentChild` array because we only required that processed array

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      SubCategories: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$SubCategories",
          initialValue: { level: -1, presentChild: [], prevChild: [] },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] },
                    "$$value.prevChild",
                    "$$value.presentChild"
                  ]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] },
                    "$$value.presentChild",
                    []
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevChild: "$$prev",
                presentChild: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            SubCategories: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: { $eq: ["$$e.sub_category", "$$this.id"] }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { SubCategories: "$SubCategories.presentChild" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OBL4OhnVOBz)

---

Without `$mergeObjects`:
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PVgq9htiXyG)

Comment: i amm getting this error `Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'`.  with mongoose version 5.11.8

Comment: what is the mongodb version?

Comment: mongoDB version is 3.4.24

Comment: $mergeObjects is from mongodb version 3.6, i have added new playground link without mergeobjects you can try that.